# private property in objective c

Tags: objective-c, properties, synthesize

I am writing class in Objective c.

and I want a private property from type double in my main view controller.

my code: MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL x;

@end

@implementation MainViewController
```

now , i know taht Automatic Property Synthesis With Xcode 4.4
but if i dont write @synthesize x;
i can access to my property "x" only with "self.x" or "_x"

and if i write 
@synthesize x

i can access with just write "x".

i know it is a simple question ,but I really want to understand what is happening in the code behind,
and  the essential difference between the two approaches.

thanks

Comment: The default is actually `@synthesize x = _x;` by saying `@synthesize x;` you are really saying `@synthesize x = x;` Does that make sense?

Comment: @DrummerB not that one, but im sure this question has been asked

Comment: I explained all this in my answer to that question, that's why I linked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `@synthesize x;` you can either use `self.x` or `x`

If you don't synthesize the property the compiler does behind the scenes this: `@synthesize x = _x`. Now you can either use `self.x` or `_x`

But you can synthesize and assign the ivar a different name as well, e.g. `@sythesize x = _aBoolen` —now you can use `self.x` or `_aBoolean`

Comment: Note that `self.x` and `_x` as accessors or setters are quite different in behavior;  the former is a KV observable method call, the latter is not.